# What does "fully static" mean in the Dagger2 documentation?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

The Google's dagger2 documentation starts with

> Dagger is a fully static, compile-time dependency injection framework...

What does "fully static" mean in this context? Isn't "compile time" enough to describe the way it works?

How can a "compile time" dependency injection framework be dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other DI frameworks that have annotation processors that run at compile time that are not fully static.

For example [Roboguice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) had an optional annotation processor. So in some sense it could claim to have a  "compile time" aspect. However, it still relied on reflection at run time for injection and so you could not claim that it was "fully static".

Qualifying "compile-time" with "fully static" distinguishes Dagger 2's salient feature i.e., complete DI code generation using an annotation processor without any need to rely on reflection.

Comment: I have read the answer many times but can't understand it.
Does fully static meant it doesn't use reflections and generate zero object in run time?

Comment: @IslamAssem yes, "fully static" means there is no runtime use of reflection to generate factories etc.